# POST JSON to controller with jquery and also use built in validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, validation, jquery-validate

I have a form which collects some data, most importantly an address which needs to be geocoded to obtain the lat and long.

Suppose the user inputs something like:

```
123 main st
SomEwheRE, NY 12345
```

My client-side javasript goes out to the Google Geocoding service and attempts to get the lat and long for that address.  In return I also get back more addition information including the properly formatted address:

```
123 Main St
Somewhere, NY 12345
```

What I want to do is replace the values in their respective textboxes so that the user can verify the data is good and then finally submit via `jQuery.post("My/Controller/", myJSONData, function(){});` but I'm getting some strange behavior.

If I type in an address and don't include a zip code (it's required in the database but not necessary to geocode the address) I get a validation error.  The thing is I would like to defer validation until after I obtain the information from the geocode service and replace the values in the textbox.

Right now, if I only type in a partial address (and hit "Submit") this is what happens:

1. Validation errors occur on the missing required fields and all my textboxes go blank
2. Hit submit again and this time the textboxes are properly filled in with the geocoded information BUT ALL fields produce validation errors.
3. Hit submit a 3rd time and now the validation errors go away and everything is as expected.  At this point, I want to consider the form valid and allow the `POST` to the `Controller`.

Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var geoCodedAddress = geoCodeAddress($("#Address1").val(), $("#City").val(), $("#State").val());
        console.log(geoCodedAddress);
        geoCodedAddress.Name = $("#Name").val();
        geoCodedAddress.Phone = $("#Phone").val();
        $("#Address1").val(geoCodedAddress.Address1);
        $("#City").val(geoCodedAddress.City);
        $("#State").val(geoCodedAddress.State);
        $("#ZipCode").val(geoCodedAddress.ZipCode);
    });
});
```

`geoCodeAddress()` returns the JSON object with the required fields filled in and that works.  I believe the problem lies somewhere between my ineptitude and the block of code I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after much tinkering this is what I came up with.  Basically, when someone hits submit (or enter) I stop the form from being submitted (by `e.preventDefault()`) and check to see if it's valid.  If the form data is valid, I then process what the user entered, fill in the form fields with the acquired data (this doesn't do anything functional, it just flashes the new data in the form).  I couldn't figure out how to submit the form, so I posted it myself using `$.post()`.  If there is a better way please leave a comment or answer and I will vote.  Here is my complete code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("form").valid()) {
            geoCodeAddress($("#Address1").val(), $("#City").val(), $("#State").val(), function (geoCodedAddress) {
                geoCodedAddress.Name = $("#Name").val();
                $("#Address1").val(geoCodedAddress.Address1);
                $("#City").val(geoCodedAddress.City);
                $("#State").val(geoCodedAddress.State);
                $("#ZipCode").val(geoCodedAddress.ZipCode);
                $("#Longitude").val(geoCodedAddress.Longitude);
                $("#Latitude").val(geoCodedAddress.Latitude);
                $.post("/Controller/Action/", geoCodedAddress, function () { $(window).attr("location", "/Controller/"); });
            });
        }
    });
});
```